# PHP: search array with similar matching keywords

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like

```
$arr = array(0 => array(id=>1,name=>"Apple"),
             1 => array(id=>2,name=>"Orange"),
             2 => array(id=>3,name=>"Grape")
);
```

I have written the code for searching the multidimensional array.

Here is it

```
function search($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();
    search_r($array, $key, $value, $results);
    return $results;
}

function search_r($array, $key, $value, &$results)
{
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return;
    }

    if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
        $results[] = $array;
    }

    foreach ($array as $subarray) {
        search_r($subarray, $key, $value, $results);
    }
}
```

But it works only for exactly matching keywords.
What I need is, If I search for 'Gra' in this array. The function should return

```
array(0 => array(id=>1,name=>"Grape")
);
```

This seems to be something like mysql %LIKE% condition.How can this be done in PHP arrays ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking if the string matches you can instead use [`strpos`](http://php.net//manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
strpos($strToCheck, 'Gra') !== false;//Will match if $strToCheck contains 'Gra'

strpos($strToCheck, 'Gra') === 0;    //Will match if $strToCheck starts with 'Gra'
```

Note that the above is case sensitive. For case insensitivity you can <s>[`strtoupper`](http://php.net//manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) both strings before comparing</s> use `strripos` instead.

In your example the check would become:

```
if (isset($array[$key]) && strpos($array[$key],$value) !== false) {
    $results[] = $array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**stristr**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.stristr.php)  function for string manipulations in php, and you'll don't have to think about different cases and cast them to uppercase.

**stristr** function is **not case sensitive**, so your code will like this

```
 if (isset($array[$key]) && stristr($array[$key], $value) !== false) {
        $results[] = $array;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Focussing on the line here that you wrote -

```
if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
```

We can modify it to search for substrings, rather than exact match -

```
if (isset($array[$key]) && strpos($array[$key], $value)) {
```

This will try to find if the value is present somewhere in the content of `$array[$key]`

Hope it helps